# Copy and paste rows with variable cell ranges fails

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I get runtime error 1004 on the first xSheet.Range in the for-loop, and I am sure the error would also occur on the 2 following.  CPC has the Value attribute and so does row.  It worked in a test sheet but there was no loop.

[image: Snipit Code]

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution to my code syntax error.  It is attached and working[image: Snipit Code]